# visual studio 2017 how to save my choice to run my project on Locall IIS and not on IISEXPRESS?

Tags: visual-studio, properties, localhost, iis-express

every time when I open in VS the properties of my project and change to open on local IIs
properties -> Apply server settings to all users -> Local IIs
after I close VS the properties change to "IIs express"
I tried to check in the project but because there is not  real change - i get the message:
"All of the changes were either unmodified files or locks. The changes have been undone by the server."
what can I do to save the change I my properties?

Comment: What exactly is the project type? ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core? "there is not real change" is expected if your changes go to a `.user` file in the project folder for ASP.NET projects, while ASP.NET Core projects use `launchSettings.json`.

Comment: no, its ASP.NET not Core